# Is there any structure on the subset of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ commuting with a finite group upto integral matrices?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Consider the group $$G = \left\langle  
\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   -1 & 0 
  \end{smallmatrix}\right]
 \right\rangle \subseteq SL_2(\mathbb{R}).$$

I want to consider the set of $ SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$\{ g \in SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ g^{-1} h g \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \text{ for each } h \in G \} \subseteq SL_2(\mathbb{R})  .$$

The condition says that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    d & -b \\
    -c & a
   \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   -1 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
   \end{bmatrix}
     \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) $$
$$\Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
 dc + ab & d^2 + b^2 \\
-a^{2} - c^{2} & -cd-ab
\end{bmatrix}
\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}).$$
It is not clear what are all the solutions for this in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

More generally, I want to consider such structures with an arbitrary finite group $G \subseteq SL_d(\mathbb{Q})$ and analogous constructions in $SL_d(\mathbb{R})$ but I don't know what structures such objects have.

Comment: A minor nitpick: I guess $G$ also has to include the opposites of these two elements, since they are the powers of the 2nd element?

Comment: What kind of a structure do you expect or look for? On general grounds, this is a reductive subgroup of $SL_d({\mathbb R})$ defined over ${\mathbb Q}$. What else would you like to know?

Comment: It's not a group. It would have been a group had the condition been $g^{-1} h g \in G$ for each $h \in G$.

Comment: @colt_browning corrected?

Comment: Your title question is asking for one thing but the body of the question us asking for something else (not a subgroup, not a commutation condition). Voting to close due to lack of clarity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan

I've changed the title

Comment: But you still call it a subgroup in the body of the question! I do not think it is even a subsemigroup.

Comment: Ah yes! It was an error, sorry.

Comment: What exactly needs more details here? I don't understand why it is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some number theory preliminaries:

> If $u,v,w$ are integers such that $w<0<v$ and $-wv=u^2+1,$ then there exists integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $-w=a^2+c^2, v=b^2+d^2,$ $u=dc+ab$ and $1=ad-bc.$

This is true due to unique factorization in the Gaussian integers, and is, really, beyond the scope of this question.

That means we get at least one matrix $M_0=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ in $ SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ which satisfies your condition to get $U=\begin{bmatrix}u&v\\w&-u\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb SL_2(\mathbb Z).$

Let $J=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}.$ So $M_0^{-1}JM_0=U.$

If $g^{-1}Jg=U=M_0^{-1}JM_{0}$ then $M_{0}g^{-1}$ commutes with $J,$ and thus must share eigenvectors with $J.$

The eigenvectors of $J$ are $\begin{bmatrix}1\\\pm i\end{bmatrix}.$ If $M_{0}g^{-1}=(g_{ij})$ this means:

$$g_{11}+g_{12}i=\lambda\\g_{21}+g_{22}i=i\lambda$$

This yields $g_{11}=\lambda_1,g_{12}=\lambda_2,$ $g_{21}=-\lambda_2,$ $g_{22}=\lambda_1.$ This $M_0g^{-1}\in SL_2$ iff $|\lambda| =1.$

So the most general solution is any matrix $M$ of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\lambda_2\\-\lambda_2&\lambda_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$ where $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2=1,$ and $a,b,c,d$ integers such that $ad-bc=1.$

That is, any rotation matrix times any element of $SL_2(\mathbb Z).$

You can restrict to $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$ and still get all such matrices.

---

The key of the number theory is not to find $a,b,c,d.$ It is to ensure that any such conjugate comes from **some** integers. Solving for $a,b,c,d$ would be messy in general, but we don't need to solve them.

Comment: Wow. 

Could you explain the part about the Gaussian integers a bit. I don't follow how to show it.

Comment: As I said, it is way too complicated to go into here. You shouldn't be able to "follow" it, since I didn't write a proof. Basically, we must be able to factor $u+i=(a-ci)(b+di)$ where $a^2+c^2=-w,$ $b^2+d^2=v.$ @Breakfastisready